# Change UILabel when countdown to a date completes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, time, uilabel

I have a countdown in my app and I need to change the text to FINISH when the countdown hits the date.

[image]

Here is the code :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
NSDate *startingDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *endingDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currentGame.gameDate]];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond;

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *componentsDaysDiff = [gregorianCalendar components:unitFlags
                                                            fromDate:startingDate
                                                              toDate:endingDate
                                                             options:0];


NSString *countdownText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Months %ld Days %ld Minutes %ld Seconds", (long)componentsDaysDiff.month, (long)componentsDaysDiff.day, (long)componentsDaysDiff.minute, (long)componentsDaysDiff.second];

gamesCountdownLabel.text = countdownText;
```

Comment: Just check whether all the components are zero... I don't understand the problem you have.

Comment: @JoshCaswell if you see the picture I have attached you are going to find that countdown - 4 days. I need the countdown when hit the date in database the label changed to released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer

here is :

```
)componentsDaysDiff.second];
if ((long)componentsDaysDiff.month <= 0 && (long)componentsDaysDiff.day <= 0 && (long)componentsDaysDiff.minute <= 0 && (long)componentsDaysDiff.second <= 0 ) {
    gamesCountdownLabel.text = @"Released";
}else{
gamesCountdownLabel.text = countdownText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation I understand that you just need to check whether the "current date" is later than the "endingDate".

You could replace:

```
gamesCountdownLabel.text = countdownText;
```

With:

```
NSDate *refDate = [NSDate date]; // current date as a reference time

gamesCountdownLabel.text = ([refDate isEqualToDate: [endingDate laterDate: refDate]) ? “FINSIH” : countdownText;
```